# What should X be?

Tags: riddle, number-sequence

3 9 3 9 3

8 6 4 8 6

2 4 2 4 2

9 8 X 8 9

What should X be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your wording implies you don't know the answer yourself. is that true?

Comment: X is definitely 5.

Comment: @IanMacDonald X is 10. *V* is 5. :-P

Answer (score 4):

We are shown two kinds of rows - those with just two values, and those with three. The ones with two values follow this pattern:

> A B A B A

The ones with three follow this pattern:

> A B C A B

Since the last line

> has the 8 and 9 in opposite order at the end,

it is a line with

> two

values. The missing number is

> 9

Comment: Interesting... If we would assume that 8 and 9 switch places in the last row so that it would become:                9 8 X 9 8

What value should X then have according to your theory?

Comment: Technically, any number would work.

Comment: @KalleB there is not enough info to be sure how the 4 in line 2 was determined, but it seems reasonable that it has the same difference (2) from 8 to 6 and from 6 to 4. Using that approach would produce 7.

Comment: @Trenin are you commenting on my original answer or answering the followup from the OP?

Comment: @KateGregory Follow up from OP - sorry, should have included a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Note: this can't be correct, but I'll leave it to inspire others.
My vote is

> 1

Each line is

> a number followed by that number squared, repeated infinitely

so

> 3 squared is 9
>  8 squared is 64
>  2 squared is 4
>  9 squared is 81

Comment: I just noticed that this must be incorrect, since the last line ends with 89 not 98.  Leaving it here in case it gives someone an idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> 9

If we take the 1st, 3rd, and 5th column of each row

1st*3rd and 3rd*5th

and then take the answer and multiply the two numbers together you get what is in the 2nd and 4th column.

**1st row:**

1st*3rd = 2nd  -> 3*3 = 9

3rd*5th = 4th  -> 3*3 = 9

**2nd row:**

8*4=32 -> 3*2 = 6

4*6=24 -> 2*4 = 8

**3rd row:**

1st*3rd = 2nd  -> 2*2=4

3rd*5th = 4th  -> 2*2=4

**4th row:**

9*9=81 -> 8*1 = 8 (2nd)

9*9=81 -> 8*1 = 8 (4th)

Comment: If this is the logic used, then the question is somewhat bad, since X could also be two.

Answer (score 0):

X should be **7**

patterns are ...

1.) `

> A B A B A

`2.)`

> A ,A-2 ,A-2-2 ,A ,A-2

`3.)`

> A ,B,A,B,A

`4.)`

> A,A-1,A-1-1,A,A-1

`

Comment: You can make spoilers by prefixing lines with `>!` not `>`

Comment: thanks for suggestion i was finding and as i am learner in this aspect i did mistake sorry for that

Comment: don't worry, there is always a first time `;)`

Comment: The last one is 98X89 not 98X98. Hence the logic does not apply.

Answer (score -1):

I'm leaning towards:

> 9 or 7. Based on the prior series, you're alternating numbers. With the series 8 6 4 8 6, it seems that it's alternating 8, 6, 4, 8, 6, 4 into infinity. If the rows have a relationship with each other then the answer could be 7 - you're subtracting 1 (the difference between the alternating numbers) from the second number in the series, and that calculation is made every other row.

Comment: You must have slipped up on your string theory, or perhaps gotten the wrong number of dimensions in your differential equations because the second example doesn't alternate and cannot be explained with the current theory.  Perhaps you need a less specialized "theory of everything" that explains this case as well.

Comment: What if the last sequence is 9, 8, 3, 8, 9, 9, 8, 3, 8, 9, ... repeated?

Comment: @Trenin I have modified my answer accordingly.